# Magento ver. 2.3.5-p1 Setup PWA store step by step Guide or documentation

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.3.5-p1, pwa, graphql, pwa-studio

I am new to PWA Studio.

Can anyone guide or suggest any `website` or `blog` tutorial for step by step installation of `PWA` storefront? Does Magento PWA require to lean `React` and `GraphQL`?

Which one is better `Magento PWA` or `Vue storefront`? Also, suggest to me if any other opensource options are available as well!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone guide or suggest any website or blog tutorial for step by step installation of PWA storefront?

The [official documentation](https://magento.github.io/pwa-studio/) is by far your best option, it is changing quite frequently at the moment and it hasn't been widely adopted so there isn't a lot of third party documentation out there.

> Does Magento PWA require to lean React and GraphQL

Yes if you would like to customise the frontend or the data served to the frontend.

> Which one is better Magento PWA or Vue storefront?

This is opinion based which isn't what Stack Exchange is for, it also depends what is important to for your project. There is no 'best' solution for everyone.